# Keep tab open on form submit - without Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I have a tabbed form that is built on the following tabs:

```
<ul class="tab">
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sydney')">Sydney</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks a tab they are taken to the corresponding city:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
</script>

<script>
var mybtn = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0];
mybtn.click();
</script>
```

I'm using php to process the form and want to retain the current tab that a user is on when they submit the form (i.e. when the form is reloaded) without using AJAX is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can submit the form to an iframe within that page.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" target="result_frame">
    <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff!" />
</form>
<iframe name="result_frame"></iframe>
```

The output of your `process.php` will be display on the iframe `result_frame`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In PHP

```
$TAB_ACTIVE = array(false, false, false);
$TAB_ACTIVE[(isset($_GET['tab']) && in_array((int) $_GET['tab'], array(0, 1, 2)) ? (int) $_GET['tab'] : 0)] = true;
```

In HTML Tab Header

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[0] ? ' class="active"' : ''); ?>><a href="yourpage.php?tab=0" data-toggle="tab">Activity Log</a></li>
                    <li<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[1] ? ' class="active"' : ''); ?>><a href="yourpage.php?tab=1" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
                    <li<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[2] ? ' class="active"' : ''); ?>><a href="yourpage.php?tab=2" data-toggle="tab">Password</a></li>
                </ul>
```

In HTML Tab body

```
<div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[0] ? ' active' : ''); ?>">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[1] ? ' active' : ''); ?>">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane<?php print ($TAB_ACTIVE[2] ? ' active' : ''); ?>">
</div>
</div>
```